# Concatenating (sub)fields of structs in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a Matlab object, that is a cell array containting structs that have almost identical structures and I want to programmatically get a (sub)field of the structs of all cell array elements.

For example, we take `test`

```
test = {struct('a',struct('sub',1)), struct('a',struct('sub',2),'b',1)};
```

This will create a cell array with the following structure:

```
cell-element 1: a --> sub --> 1
cell-element 2: a --> sub --> 2
                  \-> b --> 1
```

It can be seen that the elements of `test` don't have the exact same structure, but similar. How can I get all values of the `a.sub` fields of the elements of the cell. I can obtain them in this specific problem with

```
acc=zeros(1,numel(test));
for ii=1:numel(test)
   acc(ii) = test{ii}.a.sub;
end
```

but I can't quite get this method to work in a more general context (ie. having different fields).

Comment: What do you mean by "having different fields"? Different type of the field values? different field names?

Comment: I mean instead of accessing the field `.a.sub` of each element acessing the a different field eg. `.some.thing.else` (which I did not include in my small example cell array)

Comment: Take a look at the `getfield` function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html

Comment: `getfield` is more or less equivalent to dynamic field names `.(variable)` and cannot handle field names like `a.sub`. Therefore I cannot use this directly without somehow splitting `a.sub` on the `.`.

Comment: Read carefully the help. The function supports nested filednames, in your case being `getfield(test{ii}, 'a', 'sub')`. Look at the second example to see how you can build arbitrary lists of nested fieldnames that can be passed to the function.

Comment: okay, maybe I should put this in an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the function `getfield`:

```
%//Data to play with
test = {struct('a',struct('sub',1)), struct('a',struct('sub',2),'b',1)};

%//I'm interested in these nested fields
nested_fields = {'a', 'sub'};

%//Scan the cell array to retrieve the data array
acca = cellfun(@(x) getfield(x, nested_fields{:}), test);
```

In case your data cannot guarantee that all the elements are the same type and size, then you need to output a cell array instead:

```
%//Scan the cell array to retrieve the data cell array
accc = cellfun(@(x) getfield(x, nested_fields{:}), test, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

**Later Edit**

If one wants to use different sets of nested fields for each cell element then:

```
%//nested_fields list should have the same size as test
nested_fields = {{'a','sub'}, {'b'}};
accm = cellfun(@(x,y) getfield(x,y{:}), test, nested_fields, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: What if we want to access nested fields `a.sub` for the first struct, but just `b` for the second one? Edit: Ah maybe the `nested_fields{:}` automatically takes care of this for us? Nice!

Comment: @dfri Depends on how you want to express that. But okay, I'll update the answer to this case.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* No need for recursion, as shown by @CST-link:s answer; the native `getfield` function can neatly unfold a cell array of fields as its second argument, e.g. `getfield(foo{i}, fields{:})` instead of the call to the recursive function in my old answer below. I'll leave the recursive solution below, however, as it could have some value in the context of the question.

---

You can build you own recursive version of `getField`, taking a cell array of fields.

```
function value = getFieldRec(S,fields)
  if numel(fields) == 1 
    value = getfield(S, fields{1});
  else
    S = getfield(S,fields{1})
    fields{1} = [];
    fields = fields(~cellfun('isempty',fields));
    value = getFieldRec(S,fields);
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
foo = {struct('a',struct('sub',1)), ...
  struct('a',struct('sub',2),'b',3), ...
  struct('c',struct('bar',7),'u',5)};
accessFields = {'a.sub', 'b', 'c.bar'};

values = zeros(1,numel(foo));
for i = 1:numel(foo)
  fields = strsplit(accessFields{i},'.');
  values(i) = getFieldRec(foo{i},fields);
end
```

With the following result

```
values =

     1     3     7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this using `eval`:

```
function out = catCellStructSubField(cellStruct, fieldName)
out = zeros(1,numel(cellStruct));
for ii = 1:numel(cellStruct)
   out(ii) = eval(['cellStruct{ii}.' fieldName]);
end
```

Where it can be used on my test example like this:

```
catCellStructSubField(test, 'a.sub')
```

Dynamic field names (`cellStruct{ii}.(fieldName)`) does not work because I'm accessing sub-fields.

I know `eval` is often a bad idea. I'm curious for different solutions.